# To validate the file name from the test, how to to get mocked value from System.currentTimeMillis() that is called from a method of a class instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, powermockito

**I want to mock `System.currentTimeMillis()` method to return the mock value when `generateFileName` method called from `MyClassImpl` instance constructor.**

```
...
...

public class MyClassImpl {
    private String myFileName;

    public MyClassImpl() {
        generateFileName();
    }

    public String getMyFileName() {
        return myFileName;
    }

    private void generateFileName() {
        myFileName = "Request" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

```
...
...

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*"})
public class MyClassImplTest {

    @Test
    public void testForFileSave() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(123456789L);

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " mocked current time");

        // Act
        MyClassImpl myclass = new MyClassImpl();

        // Assert
        assertThat(myclass.getMyFileName(), is("Request" + System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

**Test response**

```
123456789 mocked current time
ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not a subtype
INFO 2021-03-05T07:45:32,390 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log [Test worker] Logging initialized @5103ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog


Expected: is "Request123456789"
     but: was "Request1614930331383"
Expected :Request123456789
Actual   :Request1614930331383
```

**How to fix this issue?**

Comment: What do you need to assert? Are the numbers absolutely necessary? Or would it suffice if you check that your fileName != null and .contains("Request")? I ran into the same problem many times myself with times/dates and it was never crucial to assert that they were exact (most of the times before/after checks were enough). Besides, if System fails, nothing works. So I really would rethink the value of such assertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a separate protected method. In the test create a test class that extends `MyClassImpl` and overrides the protected method, returning whatever you want for the test.

```
public class MyClassImpl {
    // ...

    private void generateFileName() {
        myFileName = "Request" + currentTimeMillis();
    }

    protected long currentTimeMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

public class MyClassMock extends MyClassImpl {
    @Override
    protected long currentTimeMillis() {
        return 123456789L;
    }
}
```

Instead of using this custom mock class, you can also use partial mocks (i.e. a spy in mockito).